# How can I configure Google OAuth consent screen to not show checkboxes?

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, scopes, oauth2-playground

Hi **Stackoverflow** community,

I'm trying to configure a web app to make use of certain *Google scopes*. I want the user to either approve all of them or reject all of them.

This is exactly the behavior I do get when playing around with **Google OAuth Playground**:

[image: Google OAuth Playground]

See, I get per each scope a "solid circle" that can not be unchecked.
The user either allows access to all listed scopes or denies access to all of them. All at once.

But in my app, each permission is mapped to a popup that can be **ALLOWED** or **DENIED**. Plus, at the end, the same consent screen is displayed but with the ability for the user to **select/unselect** certain permissions. (checkboxes)

[image: Scope 1]
[image: Scope 2]
[image: Consent Screen]

Even though this might sound like more granular I think this is also a little more confusing, plus it extends the logic in my app as I need to double check that permissions to all scopes have been granted. I do need both of them for doing what I need to do, so, only one scope is not useful to me, I might need to re-trigger the grant permission process: which is actually what I'm trying to avoid. I mean, it's OK to deal with the **complete denied** scenario, but having partial scopes approved is not something I do want to have.

The solution would be to emulate what **Google OAuth Playground** does.

I've added the scopes explicitly in my consent screen config (which nows figures as under review). But still I do get this behavior.

Which config or param to the oAuth url I might be missing to get that exact behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that, after adding the **specific scopes** I needed in:

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit?project={YourProjectID}

[image]

After a while... I started to see the consent screen with solid circles instead of optional checkboxes!

Comment: Hey, I've added the scopes I use (only `drive.appdata` which is not sensitive or restricted) and verified my app as well. However, I still keep seeing a checkmark for the permission(the checkmark is even unchecked initially). Do you have any idea why that might be the case?

Comment: @Max Same thing is happening to me. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @jmart check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573910/disable-checkboxes-on-google-consent-screen/65128371#65128371

Comment: Instead of requesting the permissions during login, I do a normal login and request the permissions afterward with `GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions()`. You will also need to check if your app has the needed permissions before using them, which you can do with `GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions()`

Comment: @cSn Late comment, but thank you for the solution: In the OAuth consent screen, I added ". /auth/drive", but I forgot to add "email", "profile", and "openid" because I thought they were basic permissions. After adding them, the checkboxes no longer appear.