# How can I make sure that the permissions are checked or unchecked by default in the oauth screen of the calenndar api?

Tags: oauth, google-calendar-api

In my application, the oauth screen of the calendar api has the permissions unchecked by default.

How can I make it checked by default?
How can I prevent it from being unchecked?

The scope I'm using is auth/calendar.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable checkboxes on Google consent screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573910/disable-checkboxes-on-google-consent-screen)

Comment: This is the right article! Thank you!