# avoid the checkbox or leave it by default always active the OAuth de Gmail.?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api

Hello I am doing Oauth with Google and I am requesting two scopes "email and [https://mail.google.com/"](https://mail.google.com/%22) to show oauth flow, I am using the following url

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=email%20https://mail.google.com/&access_type=offline&include_granted_scopes=true&response_type=code&state=state&redirect_uri=xxxxxx&client_id=XXXXXX
```

in this way it is shown like this:

[image]

How can I leave the gmail check selected? **I need that by default all the checkbox are selected..**

Thank you so much

Comment: Can you show us how you generated the URL in your post?

Comment: Please check this post with a similar concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573910/disable-checkboxes-on-google-consent-screen