# Pre-ticked checkboxes on Google Consent Screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

We are having trouble with the Google Consent Screen (oauth2) where the scopes we are requesting aren't ticked automatically.

This is leading to users telling us that they have given permission, but they actually haven't as they weren't aware they needed to tick the boxes in order to give permission.

Is there a way to have these checkboxes pre-ticked? Or perhaps not allow users to tick/untick them? Just give users the option to accept or not?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No, only checking the scopes when the user logs in and sending them to a message to give the extra scopes :(

Comment: You may find this approach useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69470478/4195337

Comment: Any update on this issue? I am facing the same issue of permission not coming pre-checked using google sign in with JS.

Comment: We changed how we approach this. Now we log the user in and don't request any permissions at that point. Instead we now requet permissions as we need them. Then there's only one thing that's needed at a time and we can handle exceptions more contextually.

Answer (score 0):

We are having the same issue here. As a temporary solution we reduced the amount of the scopes (checkboxes) to only one `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, which is enough to view/create files in drive (didn't test deletion/update though).

Comment: Hello Tem Ab, i have tried your solution but it also didn't work for me, I want to pre-ticked contacts checkbox, I have applied `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts` in scopes still contact permission are not coming pre-ticked.

There is also open github issues relalated to that: [github issue](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/754)