# Google OAuth consent screen: How do I know the user grants the requested access?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm building an Angular application that uses the [Google API Client Library for JavaScript](https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client) and it requires user permissions at login.
Permission to access Google Drive is required, but it is not checked when the consent screen is initially displayed.
So I need to know if the user has checked that checkbox on the consent screen to make sure the app works correctly.
How do I know that from the JavaScript code?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response from the token endpoint (`https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token`) contains a `scope` field. This field tells you which scopes were *actually* granted:

```
{
  "access_token": "ya29.A0...",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email openid",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "id_token": "ey..."
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I'm using Google API JavaScript Library and don't want to handle the raw data of the response if possible...  I eventually found another solution ( rather, it was a mistake in my settings ) that kept the screen from showing the check boxes acorrding to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61103955/14952561).

Comment: Sorry for the wrong information. It seems that showing the checkbox is something that [cannot be avoided.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573910/disable-checkboxes-on-google-consent-screen/65128371#65128371) And I found [gapi.auth2.AuthResponse](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse) is the method that returns the response Johanness said above. I'll try this. Thanks.

Comment: Hey what's the equivalent in python to find this token?